# Android Mobile Unable to connect local devices or internet at some regular intervals

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, android

I bought new D-Link DIR-X1560 router. Sometimes in my mobile I lose internet connection. I can't even open router local home website (http://192.168.1.1). And this is happening to recently bought **mi box 4k**.
I gave static ip to **mi box** to fix. But even giving static ip in my mobile not working. This happens 2 to 3 hrs. every other day. Everything is fine while using old dir 860 router.

Comment: Bring back that device to the shop, replace it with something else; not D-link.

Comment: WiFi is a shared media and for the 2.4 GHz band there are only 3 possible collision-free frequencies. Therefore the new router may use a different frequency that collides with another WiFi of your neighbors. Try to set the router to a different WiFi frequency.

Comment: BTW. You should really read the manual, then you would know that the router IP is  `http://192.168.0.1`

Comment: Is the dropout only affecting one Android device when this happens?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart yes, mostly one or two devices.